# Android room первоначальное заполнение базы

Tags: android, android-room

Есть БД на room, которая создаётся автоматически при первом запуске приложения.

Вопрос. Как правильно заполнить её таблицы "стартовыми" значениями? Через миграции или использовать DAO?

Comment: Мне кажется, что особой разницы нет. Однако, если данных однотипных много, то, считаю, лучше программно в рантайме при первом запуске считать их из к-л JSON файла и положить в БД, чем эти же данные через миграции писать, ибо проще JSON править, чем SQL. Если же их совсем мало и они все разные, то можно, наверное, и через миграции. В общем, считаю, что это дело вкуса)